# Form is not showing in tabs

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble displaying the form, in the div tabs. Any quick solution without changing a whole lot of code or using javascript?

I'm quite new, and have used a tutorial of youtube to create the responsive tabs using only css and html. Please ignore the nav bar as i will be fixining, just the tabs and forms.

```css
nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #3C3939;
  height: 100%;
  /*full height */
  position: fixed;
  /* Make it stick, even on scroll */
  overflow: auto;
  /* enable scrolling if the sidenav has too much content */
}

li a {
  display: block;
  /* links as block elements, whole link area click */
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 1px;
  /*padding between pages*/
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* change link color on hover */

li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #F3ECEC;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #3C3939;
  background-color: #3C3939;
}

.title1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #572222;
  background-color: #3C3939;
  padding-top: 20px;
}


/* NAV ENDS */


/* TABS STRS */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6
}

.container {
  max-width: 452px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
  bottom: 10%;
}

.tab_trigger {}

.tab_trigger ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.tab_trigger ul li {
  width: 50%;
}

.tab_trigger ul li label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

.tab_trigger ul li:nth-child(1) label {
  background: rgb(90, 72, 72);
}

.tab_trigger ul li:nth-child(2) label {
  background: rgb(90, 72, 72);
}

.tab_container_wrap {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 590px;
}

.tab_container_wrap input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  top: -10000px;
}

.tab_container_wrap input:checked+.tab_content_box {
  display: block;
}

.tab_container_wrap :-ms-input-placeholder:checked+.tab_content_box {
  display: block;
}


/* CONTENT BOX SWITCH*/

.tab_content_box {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 590px;
}

.tab_content_box h2 {
  margin: 0 0 20px
}

.tab_content_box:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #3C3939;
  display: none;
}

.tab_content_box:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #3C3939;
  overflow: visible;
}


/* END CONTENT BOX SWITCH */


/* END TABS */


/* STYLING SCRUMS STRT */

.scrums2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Organize</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css" hreflang="test.py" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="title">
          <h1>Organize</h1>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Folders</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Timeline</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Meetings</a></li>
      <li>
        <div class="title1">
          <h3>documents</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- TABS -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tab_trigger">
      <ul>
        <li><label for="tab1">Messages</label></li>
        <li><label for="tab2">scrums</label></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab_container_wrap">
      <input type="radio" checked id="tab1" name="1">
      <!-- MESSAGES -->
      <div class="tab_content_box">
        <h2>Messages</h2>
        <p>YOU KNOW WHAT</p>
      </div>
      <!-- MESSAGES END -->
      <input type="radio" checked id="tab2" name="1">
      <!-- SCRUMS -->
      <div class="tab_content_box">
        <h2>Scrums</h2>
        <p>hi</p>
        <div class="scrums2">
          <div class="form">
            <p>hi</p>
            <ul>
              <p>hi</p>
              <li>hi<input type="text" id="a" name="a" placeholder="What did you do today?"></li>
              <li><input type="text" id="b" name="b" placeholder="Obstacles faced?"></li>
              <li><input type="text" id="c" name="c" placeholder="What did you do yesterday?"></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- SCRUMSEND -->
      <!-- TABSEND -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: fixed :) any future people answer : 'code' .tab_container_wrap input{} needed an input type by doing .tab_container_wrap input[type=radio]

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can answer your own questions.

Comment: Thanks Slavi, i have just found that out now just getting used to the website that is all :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed :) any future people answer :

`.tab_container_wrap input{}` needed an input type by doing `.tab_container_wrap input[type=radio]`
otherwise, input elements that are in the div container will be hidden.

Here is a sample code of the answer.

```css
.tab_container_wrap input[type="radio"]{
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index: -100;
    top: -10000px;
    
    
}
.tab_container_wrap input:checked + .tab_content_box{
    display: block;
}
.tab_content_box:nth-of-type(1){
    background:#3C3939;
    display: none;
    
}
.tab_content_box:nth-of-type(2){
    background: #3C3939;
    display: none;
}
```